# PDF em Binário DOMPDF laravel

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

Estou com um problema no laravel ao montar um PDF. Ele dá a saída toda em binário. Estou sando o https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf

Vejam o código:

```
      public function relatorio($id)
      {
        $pedidos_id = Pedidos::find($id);

        $pedidos['pedidos'] = Pedidos::select(
        'pedidos_id',
        'cliente_id',
        'pedidos.observacao',
        'pedidos.especificacoes',
        'pedidos.frete',
        'pedidos.data',
        'pedidos.numero_pedido',
        'pedidos.preco_ipi',
        'clientes.nome as nome_cliente',
        'clientes.endereco as endereco_cliente',
        'clientes.telefone as telefone_cliente',
        'clientes.email as email_cliente',
        'clientes.uf as estado_cliente',
        'fornecedores.nome as nome_fornecedor',
        'pedidos.total_m2',
        'pedidos.total_m3',
        'pedidos.total'
        )
        ->join('clientes','clientes_id', '=', 'cliente_id')
        ->join('fornecedores','fornecedores_id', '=', 'fornecedor_id')
        ->orderBy('pedidos.data')
        ->where('pedidos_id',$pedidos_id)->get();
        // dados do pedido
        if(!$pedidos)
        {
        return response()->json([
        'message'   => 'Nenhum pedido encontrado',
      ], 404);
    }

  $pdf = PDF::loadView('pedidos', $pedidos);
  return $pdf->download('relatorio.pdf');
  }
```

SAÍDA

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Na verdade esse é o pdf mesmo se voce abrir no bloco de notas por exemplo, mas ja tentou usar o `$pdf->stream();` pra ver o que sai ao invés do download? Sua view **pedidos** existe e está correta?

Comment: Será que não é a rota que está errada? Ela está assim: Route::get('retorna_relatorio/{pedidos_id}','PedidosController@relatorio');

Comment: Não deveria, se fosse na rota a pagina nem carregaria, mas tente deixar a rota assim e usa o stream pra testar, o que pode tentar também é fazer com post no lugar do get. O load do pdf está sendo feito, só não está fazendo o download (isso pode ser por causa do get, mas nao tenho certeza, teria que testar)

Comment: Onde exatamente se está chamando essa rota? o problema é antes!

Comment: @VirgilioNovic fiz o relatório mas ele sai a programação do php. veja na imagem acima

Comment: Assim tem código a mais (não necessário) `$pedidos_id = Pedidos::find($id);` essa linha por exemplo saca fora não precisa, já pode trazer os dados só com a parte de baixo se retornar blz se não tem problemas em algum parte, a sua rota tem a variável `pedidos_id`, então o paramento do método segue o mesmo nome  `relatorio($pedidos_id)`, tente essas mudanças

Answer (score 1):

Troque $pdf->download(); por $pdf->stream(); enquanto acontece o erro para não precisar fazer o download do arquivo a cada vez que isso ocorre.

Verifique se a variável $pedidos que você está passando para a view está chegando corretamente, pois, como a view não está entendendo os dados passados, possivelmente o erro esteja quando você passa $pedidos da controller para a view.